# How can i open alertdialog box on spinnerview click?

Tags: android

i have one spinnerview. i want to open alertdialog box on spinnerview click.

I'm using the code below it works, but i can't add string in adapter

```
sp1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Wantto.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.age);
        dialog.setTitle("Age");
        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
        lv2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_num));
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }


});

sp1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Wantto.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.age);
        dialog.setTitle("Age");
        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
        lv2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_num));
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }


});
sp1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Wantto.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.age);
        dialog.setTitle("Age");
        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
        lv2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_num));
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }


});
```

how can i soleve it.problem comes here `lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item1),lv_num));`

Answer (score 0):

Declare the dialog in `onCreateInstance()`

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Wantto.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.age);
```

and call this method in TouchListener otherwise use this,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getParent());
```

initializing view or alert inside another child or subview is not working some times its throws exception ,force may also occur.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by:

1. Sub-classing Spinner
2. Overriding the performClick() method to spawn your own dialog.